# DataTable get data of tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i've built up a table with dataTable jQuery plugin.
I am trying to get the td data of a tr element by clicking on that tr.
I've read the documentation which says that i have to use "fnGetData", but when i try that, i get the error:

TypeError: table.fnGetData is not a function

var data = table.fnGetData( this );

My js Code:

```
 $('#customerTable tbody').on('click','tr', function(){
    var data = table.fnGetData( this );
    alert(data);
});
```

My DataTable is initialized as the following, working well without the click event:

```
var table = $('#customerTable').DataTable( {..});
```

Do I have to bind another plugin script in my html head section?

Regards.

Comment: I can not test it right now, but Why not bind the click directly on the tr in the first place?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code, i don't quite understand what you mean by "directly on the tr in the first place". Regards    EDIT: 
I thought it would be good to use the method of dataTable to access the data. Sure i can build a workaround with "pure jquery", but i think the dataTable method with fnGetData is better.

Comment: Ok i just found out that i have to use a special plugin for that from dataTables.
Was not described very well in their documentation:

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.1/css/dataTables.tableTools.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.1/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah, their docs are crap

Comment: Yep, they want to make money by purchasing support .. nevermind, thanks for your attention to help :)

Comment: To me it seems there is a difference if you initialize it with `dataTable({...})` vs `DataTable({...})`. http://jsfiddle.net/vt573y28/

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is a difference in the API datatables provides whether you initialize it with `DataTable({..})` vs `dataTable({..})`. The differences can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216454/597419).

Since you initialized it with the newer API you should instead in your listener use.

```
var data = table.row( this.rowIndex-1 ).data();
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vt573y28/1/)**

If you used `dataTable({..})` to initialize your table the code that you posted should work.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vt573y28/)**

Comment: This may return the wrong row if the data has been reordered