# $(...).DataTable(...).rows is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I added to my project the *jquery.dataTables.min.js (1.10.3 version)* (**called js1 for convenience**) to use `DataTable().rows().nodes()` function (and others) and its works fine.

Now, I'm trying to implement a nested table with Datatable plugin, here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/headwinds/zz3ch/) (in the same page of my project).

As you can see in the fiddle is used:

*http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js*
(**called js2 for convenience**)

that is different from js1.

This two different plugin serve both. 
Because without js1 I get this error:

*Using `$(...).DataTable(...).rows is not a function` or `$(...).dataTable(...).rows is not a function` I always get the same error.*

Without js2 nested table in the jsfiddle does not work.

So, I added both two plugins to my page. But I get the error (.row is not ...) yet.

See the new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6wujegL/1/) with the error.

Answer (score 2):

the `.DataTable()` contructor returns the new api introduced in **1.10**.

To have the old functionality, use the `.dataTable()` constructor.

If you need both the new api functionality and the old one, you can use the `.dataTable()` constructor to create your table object and use the new api like this: `myTable.api().whateverFunction()`

Comment: Can you give me more information about myTable.api().whateverFunction()?

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25216454/15089) for a more detailed description of .dataTable() vs. .DataTable().

Comment: .api() works only if I don't use js2.. Otherwise I get ".api().. is not a function.."

Comment: Yes, because in your case js1 is the datatables version 1.10.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error with the same version.

I "fix" it doing the following steps

**Step 1**

Open console in your web

**Step 2**

Create a variable of your dataTable

Ex:

```
    var p = $('#my_table').dataTable();
```

**Step 3**

Now you write "p" and a dot and you have all of the aviable functions. I dont know why but I have differents names of the functions. I just search what I need.

Hope may help.

Comment: I don't understand the Step 3

Comment: In the console, write "p" (the name of the variable) and a dot "p." and will appear all of the functions.

Comment: mmm looking for the solution I found this try it: $('#my_table').dataTable().DataTable().rows();

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
var table = $('#myDataTableuser2349').dataTable()
var data = table.fnGetData()
console.log("data",data);
```