# JQuery Data Table is not working when first loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a JQuery data table with sorting,searching and page row limit functions. Searching is working fine.

But sorting and  page row limit function is not working firstly loaded page. 
If i search something and try  page row limit function and sorting then working fine.

My script code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
        "serverside": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "deferLoading": 57,
        "displayStart": 20,
        "order":[2, "asc"]

    });

});
</script>
```

(this script is after the  table html code.)

I can't figure out the error here. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use "DataTable" instead of "dataTable"?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable();
});
```

[dataTable() vs. DataTable() - why is there a difference and how do I make them work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207147/datatable-vs-datatable-why-is-there-a-difference-and-how-do-i-make-them-w)

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23540/datatable-vs-datatable

There is also an example for the order function with DataTable: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: I changed "dataTable" to "DataTable". But issue is not corrected.