# datatable custom dropdown for sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable

I have below dropdown.

```
<select name="sortBy" id="sortBy">
    <option value="0_asc" selected="selected">Reference #</option>
    <option value="0_desc">Reference # (desc)</option>
    <option value="pe-sku-column_asc">Part # (asc)</option>
    <option value="pe-sku-column_desc">Part # (desc)</option>
    <option value="pe-title-column_asc">Description (asc)</option>
    <option value="pe-title-column_desc">Description (desc)</option>
    <option value="pe-price-column_asc">Price (asc)</option>
    <option value="pe-price-column_desc">Price (desc)</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to sort my `datatable` according to the dropdown selection

I tried this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var oTable = $('#super-product-table').DataTable({
        dom: 't'
    });

    $('#myInputTextField').keyup(function () {
        oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
    })

    $("#sortBy").change(function () {

        oTable.fnSort([[1, 'asc']]);
    })
});
```

But it gives me

> TypeError: oTable.fnSort is not a function

I have search for [fnsort](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4528/fnsort-osettings-aocolumns-icolumn-is-undefined) in `datatable.js` and found it.

One more thing, when I change `DataTable` to `dataTable` sorting started working and custom search stop.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216454/1407478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216454/1407478) provided by @davidkonrad about differences between `dataTable()` and `DataTable()`.

If you want to use `DataTable()`, replace older API method `fnSort` with newer API method [`order()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()). For example:

```
oTable.order([1, 'asc']).draw();
```

See [conversion guide for DataTables 1.10](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) for more information.