# DataTables: .ajax is not defined?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables to display some JSON data successfully. I want to reload the data source with some slightly different JSON, but I am getting errors.

I am calling in DataTables with this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jqc-1.12.4/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

And I am initializing DataTables with this JS code:

```
$(function(){
    var apiUrl = '/api/people.php';
    var table = dt('#peopleTable').dataTable({
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl,
            dataSrc: function (json) {
                return $.parseJSON(json);
            }
        },
        columns: [...] // column definitions here
    });
```

All of this so far works fine, no problems.  The problems are to follow...

So I have this click handler:

```
    $('.people-type').on('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        table.ajax.url(apiUrl + '?type=' + id).load();
        table.draw();
    });
```

When this click handler is run, I am told that `table.ajax is not defined`.  Indeed `console.log(table);` reveals the same thing, although it does seem that `table` is bound to something that looks like a DataTables object:

[image: console.log output of table]

The documentation tells me that my code is correct: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()#Example

But obviously my DataTables doesn't have the ajax method.  Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dataTable() vs. DataTable() - why is there a difference and how do I make them work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207147/datatable-vs-datatable-why-is-there-a-difference-and-how-do-i-make-them-w)

Comment: Hi @miken32 - the answer that I marked as correct 5 years ago answered my question.  You can see it below here, just under these comments.  Many thanks.

Comment: It's just a canned comment that goes along with a vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is dataTable() vs. DataTable(). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207147/datatable-vs-datatable-why-is-there-a-difference-and-how-do-i-make-them-w). In your javascript replace the line `var table = dt('#peopleTable').dataTable` with `var table = dt('#peopleTable').DataTable` and check if `ajax` is working